# Determining the center of the ellipse and its two foci

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry

My question is: Find the equation of the ellipse whose focus is $(1,2)$ and directrix is $3x+4y+5=0$ and having eccentricity $1/2$ and then determine its center and its two foci. I get the equation of such an ellipse and it is of the form:
\begin{align*}
91 x^2 - 230 x + 84 y^2 - 240 y - 24 xy - 475 = 0.
\end{align*} 
How could I get the the center and the two foci of this ellipse ?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to use the [canonical conversion method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Conversion_to_canonical_form) in order to get the coordinates of the ellipse
$$91 x^2 - 230 x + 84 y^2 - 240 y - 24 xy - 475 = 0$$

whose plot is given by Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

In the case of a conic session given in by the following equation

$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A&\frac B2\\\frac B2&C\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and the determinant $S$ of the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A&\frac B2&\frac D2\\\frac B2&C&\frac E2\\\frac D2&\frac E2&F\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ determine the standard form of the ellipse:

$$\frac{x'^2}{a^2}+\frac{y'^2}{b^2}=1$$

where $a^2=\frac{-S}{\ \ \lambda_1^2\lambda_2}$ and $b^2=\frac{-S}{\ \ \lambda_1\lambda_2^2}$.

Substituting the parameters we get $\lambda_1=100$, $ \lambda_2=75$ and $S=-6\,315\,000$. So, $a^2=8.42$, $a\approx=2.9$ $b^2\approx11.227.$, $b=\approx 3.35$.

The equation and the plot of the ellipse in the standard coordinate system are

$$\frac{x^2}{8.42}+\frac{y^2}{11.227}=1$$

and

[image]

Looking at the right triangle in the figure $f$ can be determined by solving the equation

$$a^2=b^2+f^2.$$

---

The [center of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections#Center) is given by the following formulas

$$x_c=\frac{BE-2CD}{4AC-B^2}$$
$$y_c=\frac{DB-2AE}{4AC-B^2}.$$

The original axes of the ellipse is given by the eigenvectors of  $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A&\frac B2\\\frac B2&C\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. In our case the eigenvectors are $(-4,3)$ and $(3,4)$. Given the center, the direction of the eigenvectors, and $f$, the coordinates of the foci can be easily calculated.